# how can i access global variables in fragment in kotlin language?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

actually what is the wrong in my code. globally "currentUserStatus" variable shows null. anyway i am new for android kotlin.
below my details ....

class SentMessageFragment : Fragment() {

```
private var currentUserStatus: String? = null

private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sent_message, container, false)

        
       firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

       //============ globally currentUserStatus variable shows null

        checkUserCurrentStatus()

        return view
    }

    private fun checkUserCurrentStatus() {
        var userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
        userRef.addValueEventListener( object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    var user = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                    currentUserStatus = user!!.getUser()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onDataChange` is asynchronous. So `currentUserStatus` will be null until `onDataChange` is called.  Also, please put more details in your question.  You aren't actually using `currentUserStatus` anywhere - you are only setting it within `onDataChange`.  So depending on how/when you use it, it may or may not be null.

Comment: of course it less code. mainly i want to access globally  currentUserStatus in onCreateView method.

Comment: you can access it, but it will probably be null.  The best place to use `currentUserStatus` is within the `onDataChange` function, because that is the only place you are sure to have it.  

Or, if you are capable, use a Reactive coding style (with LiveData or Rx) to react to the response when it comes in, and make changes to the UI accordingly.

Comment: understood. thnk you very much